# How to add spark-core-assembly-0.7.0.jar to classpath in Ubuntu to run a Spark project

Tags: scala, jar, apache-spark

I am new to Spark. I am trying to run a simple spark project in local system.
So based on tutorials I have run 'sbt/sbt assembly'. Now jar file is created in core/target/scala-2.9.2/spark-core-assembly-0.7.0.jar. To run samples could you please tell **where and how I have to add this jar to classpath**?

Regards,
Dinesh

Answer (score 2):

The Spark documentation's quick start guide has documentation on developing standalone applications using Spark with [Scala](https://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#a-standalone-app-in-scala) and [Java](https://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#a-standalone-app-in-java).  Those instructions show how to add a Spark dependency to your Maven or SBT projects.

If you're not using Maven or SBT to build your project, you'll have to pass the appropriate flags to `javac` and `java` to add the Spark assembly JAR to your classpath, the same as you'd do for any other JAR dependency.

As an aside, 0.7.0 is a pretty old version of Spark (it was released almost a year ago); I'd recommend using a [newer version](https://spark.incubator.apache.org/downloads.html), such as 0.9.0.